# How can the Lestrange bloodline still exist?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

If we believe the story of Leta Lestrange, her brother Corvus

> is actually dead - and so is Leta after her fight with Grindelwald.

No other children of her father were mentioned..

> So there is no male heir to carry on the bloodline.

But we know that a few decades later, some Lestranges do exist (mentioned in the HBP) and eventually there are Rodolphus and Rabastan Lestrange.

Any ideas?

Comment: `No other children of her father were mentioned` - not only that, but the film makes a big deal of him possibly being the last lost heir of the family.

Comment: As others say the Lestrange family could be continued by other branches of the family.  If the descendants of a man die out the family can be continued by descendants of that man's brothers, 1st cousins, 2nd cousins, etc.  As an extreme example, when William III of the Netherlands died in 1890 the Netherlands was inherited by his daughter Wlhelmina, but the Grand Duchy of Luxembourg was inherited by Adolph, his 17th cousin once removed in the male line. Count Henry II of Nassau, the common ancestor of the 2 branches, died in 1247, 643 years before 1890.

Comment: When Henry III of France died in 1589, the last king of France with surviving descendants in the legitimate male line was Louis IX who died in 1270, eleven generations back.  How far back do wizard pedigrees go?

Comment: Well, when a Pureblood loves his cousin very much...  On a more serious note - I may have overlooked it, but do we have any confirmation that Corvus Sr is actually dead and unable to father another heir?

Comment: I found some more information for you! :)

Answer (score 31):

## The Lestrange bloodline can continue through another branch.

The Lestrange bloodline could continue on through another male member of the bloodline though Leta’s father Corvus Sr. has no living descendants. It doesn’t have to have continued through him to have continued past his generation. It can continue through another branch. On the Lestrange family tree, there are other branches shown reaching nearly as far upwards as Corvus Sr.’s, the one ending with baby Corvus and Leta, meaning those branches likely have members who’d still be alive at a similar time period as Corvus Sr. was and they’d still be able to continue the bloodline.

[image]

Corvus Sr.’s is only one branch on the larger Lestrange family tree. The branches that have Fulcran Lestrange and Cyrille Lestrange seem to have a comparable number of generations as Corvus Sr.’s branch, so the bloodline has continued to Corvus Sr.’s generation through other branches as well. One of those branches can continue it further, since a new Lestrange could be born to one of them sometime in the late 1920s or 1930s, so the baby may not have appeared on the tree yet. There’s a male Lestrange who went to Hogwarts when Tom Riddle did, meaning he’d be born somewhere around 1926 since he’d have to be born, at the most, seven years apart from Tom for his attendance at Hogwarts to overlap with Tom - it’s possible he was born to parents from one of those other branches, and then the bloodline would have continued with his parents then possibly through him, as being male, he could pass on the Lestrange name.

> “Good gracious, is it that time already?’ said Slughorn. ‘You’d better get going, boys, or we’ll all be in trouble. Lestrange, I want your essay by tomorrow or it’s detention.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

One of those other branches could have the parents of the Lestrange who went to Hogwarts with Tom Riddle - he might not have been born yet, so he may not be on the tree. It’s not clear how he’s related to Corvus Lestrange Sr. but he was born to parents that were Lestranges, since he’s born a Lestrange. The line was clearly able to continue through another branch than Corvus Sr.’s, and if that Lestrange wasn’t born when the tree is seen, wouldn’t be shown yet.

## The tree doesn’t show all the Lestranges.

Also, the Lestrange family tree in the French Ministry only shows the descendants of Corvus and Cyrille Lestrange, it doesn’t show all the Lestranges. Radolphus Lestrange, who was the British Minister of Magic from 1835 to 1841, isn’t shown on it.

> **Radolphus Lestrange**
>   
> **1835 - 1841**
>   
> Reactionary who attempted to close down the Department of Mysteries, which ignored him. Eventually resigned due to ill health, which was widely rumoured to be inability to cope with the strains of office. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ministers for Magic (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)*</sup></sub>

He would have likely been born during a generation that would be able to be depicted on the tree. As he was Minister from 1835 to 1841, he was certainly born by 1927, and he likely wouldn’t be sufficiently far in the past that he’d be born in the time before the Lestrange family tree covers. Therefore, presumably the reason he’s not shown on the tree is because he’s not descended from either Corvus or Cyrille Lestrange, and is from a different part of the Lestrange bloodline not depicted on this tree.

[image]

It’s also possible that Rodolphus and Rabastan are descended from him, rather than any of the Lestranges on the tree. It may be even more likely that they’re descended from him, as Rodolphus has a name very similar to his, and it seems to be a Lestrange family tradition to name male children after their father. Also, the Lestrange family is listed on the Sacred Twenty-Eight, a list of the truly pure-blood families in Britain made in the early 1930s.

> In the early 1930s, a ‘Pure-Blood Directory’ was published anonymously in Britain, which listed the twenty-eight truly pure-blood families, as judged by the unknown authority who had written the book***, with ‘the aim of helping such families maintain the purity of their bloodlines’. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Pure-Blood (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood)*</sup></sub>

That means the Lestrange bloodline continued in Britain as well.

Comment: @Rawling It does help answer how the line continues. It proves that, yes, there is another male Lestrange that exists other than Corvus - his father presumably wasn’t Corvus Lestrange Sr. but his parents had him and he’d have the ability to pass on the Lestrange name.

Comment: The question doesn't actually ask how the line continues, it asks how it's possible that it does.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to examine the tree closely, but given the number of "wives" Corvus had, and his ... er ... proclivities in his method of acquiring him, it seems quite likely there were other half-siblings from other wives out there too.

Answer (score 9):

None of what you reference is reason to believe that there are no other men carrying the Lestrange family name. If her father had one or more brothers, and those brothers had one or more sons, then the name lives on.

If at some point she stated that there are no such men, then either (in-universe) she's mistaken, or (out-of-universe) it's an error on the part of the script writer.

Comment: If she says the name dies out with her brother, and yet it didn't die out, it must be due to cousins. If she had known about them, she wouldn't have said the name would die out. Therefore, she didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

**Corvus could very well still be alive.**

Leta didn't actually see the baby drown as we can see in her Boggart, that's what she thinks happened, she only saw the boat crash on a wave.

She switched Corvus with Credence, since Credence is a wizard there's a high chance his mom, who carried Corvus in the crashing boat, was also a witch and would've been able to save Corvus.

Answer (score -2):

There are many possibilities, including that:

1. the father had a sister (or other female relative) who passed on her name,
2. a descendant born with a different last name (re)adopted it.

Comment: This appears to be idle speculation, do you have any evidence you can [edit] in?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: The question is asking for "Any ideas?", so speculation seems to be called for. Idle? I don't know. What kind of evidence did you have in mind?

Comment: Evidence usually means quotes from the books/films, family trees etc. Look at Bellatrix's answer and its various revisions for an idea.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Well, Bellatrix was uniquely suited to answer this particular question...